# how do i make my bot send random messages as a DM

Tags: python, discord

My bot does not send a random DM when I type up the command for it.
What is incorrect in my code?
I don't understand what is wrong.
is there something wrong with

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def meowzdm(ctx):
    variable = [
        "Hi im a bot and i wish you a good day!",
        "Hi, my name is Meowzbot and i hope you sleep well tonight!",
        "Hello, thanks for using this command, now i can tell you that you are a great human!"
        "did you know: a person who uses this command is a very kind person!"]
    await client.message.author.send(ctx.message.author.send, "{}".format(random.choice(variable)))
```

Here is the rest of my code

```
import discord
import os
import time
import discord.ext
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, CheckFailure, check
import random
#^ basic imports for other features of discord.py and python ^

client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')  #put your own prefix here


@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print ("bot online")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "pong"
    )  #simple command so that when you type "!ping" the bot will respond with "pong!"


@client.command()
async def pong(ctx):
    await ctx.send("ping")


@client.command()
async def meow(ctx):
    await ctx.send("woof")


@client.command()
async def woof(ctx):
    await ctx.send("meow")


@client.command()
async def pizza(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
      "keanu's favourite pizza is bbq chicken        gabriel's is BBQ meat lovers"
    )


@client.command()
async def nicejob(ctx):
    await ctx.send("well done! you did it!    congrats now do more good stuff")


@client.command()
async def nevergonna(ctx):
    await ctx.send("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")


@client.command()
async def voicecrack(ctx):
    await ctx.send("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjDebmqFRuc")


@client.command()
async def botquestion(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "i have no idea why i was created other than that i can be used to tell stories and message funny things back to you"
    )


@client.command()
async def highfive(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "highfive!"
    )


@client.command()
async def coding(ctx):
    await ctx.send("here is where i was coded from!: https://replit.com/~")


@client.command()
async def bruh(ctx):
    await ctx.send("*bruh moment intensifies*")

@client.command()
async def commandlist(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "here is a list of my commands: ping, pong, meow, woof, pizza, nicejob, nevergonna, voicecrack, botquestion, highfive, coding, bruh, bothype, botdm, meowzmessage and of course, commandlist and cl.   your welcome by the way.        *P.S. commandlist and cl are the same command* *P.P.S. you need to use ! at the start of each command*"
    )

@client.command()
async def cl(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "here is a list of my commands: ping, pong, meow, woof, pizza, nicejob, nevergonna, voicecrack, botquestion, highfive, coding, bruh, bothype, botdm, meowzmessage and of course, commandlist and cl.   your welcome by the way.        *P.S. commandlist and cl are the same command* *P.P.S. you need to use ! at the start of each command*"
    )

@client.command()
async def bothype(ctx):
    await ctx.send("LETS GO WE HAVE OUR OWN BOT!   *that's me by the way!*")

@client.command()
async def botdm(ctx):
  await ctx.message.author.send('hello im a bot and i am here to wish you a good day!')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def meowzdm(ctx):
    variable = [
        "Hi im a bot and i wish you a good day!",
        "Hi, my name is Meowzbot and i hope you sleep well tonight!",
        "Hello, thanks for using this command, now i can tell you that you are a great human!"
        "did you know: a person who uses this command is a very kind person!"]
    await client.message.author.send(ctx.message.author.send, "{}".format(random.choice(variable)))


client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: Can you supply the rest of the code? for example did you add `client.add_command(meowzdm)` to your script?

Comment: well this is the first time i have coded but i don't know what that means but heres the start of my code but no that client.add_command(meowzdm) isn't a part of my script
and yes thats the enitire cript for that command        
  
import discord
import os
import time
import discord.ext
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, CheckFailure, check
import random

Comment: You can edit your original question and add the code there in a code snippet format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues that I can see. first in your original question:

```
await client.message.author.send(ctx.message.author.send, "{}".format(random.choice(variable)))
```

should be

```
await ctx.message.author.send("{}".format(random.choice(variable)))
```

then also there is this part in your full code:

```
client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

You are mixing up your `discord.Client` and your `commands.Bot` objects by calling them by the same name

you can fix that by changing

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

to

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

then replacing the `client.command` calls in your decorators to `bot.command`

Comment: thank you so much! Now that it works i can get my friends to do it so they all have their own private messages! this means alot to me so thank you again!